# PKPassLibrary remotePaymentPasses on iPad: does it return passes added on watch through phone?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, passkit

Say if I add a pass on my watch through my iPhone, and on iPad I try to get remote passes using `remotePaymentPass`, its documentation says:

> An array containing all the passes stored on a remote device (for
>   example, Apple Watch) that is paired with the current iOS device.

so I assume I won't get the passes on my watch because my watch cannot be paired with my ipad which doesn't fit **that is paired with the current iOS device**?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may pair your watch to iPad then run this method again.

'Cause iPad is your "current paired iOS device".

Try it and let us know about!

Comment: Apple Wallet and PKPassLibrary is not available on iPad. Also, Apple Watch cannot be paired with iPad.